# Is there such thing as a 1 kg "decimeter cube?"

Tags: manipulatives

Base 10 sets are readily available from educational suppliers and retail sites, as are the largest element in these sets, sometimes known as "decimeter cubes" (10 x 10 x 10 cm).

The "unit cubes" (1 x 1 x 1 cm) in such sets are the basis for the larger cousins, including "rods" and "flats." (See [here](http://mathsmaterials.com/base-ten-blocks/) for more info.)

The unit cubes that I use, made by SI Manufacturing, weigh exactly one gram each so they can be utilized for a range of STEM activities. I think this kind of cube is fairly common.

**However, I can't locate any decimeter cubes that have a mass of one kilogram, i.e., the equivalent of 1,000 my unit cubes. The models that I can find seemed to be designed to be lighter weight, presumably to reduce costs. Has anyone heard of a 1 kg decimeter cube? Can you recommend a source?**

[image: Image of Base-Ten Set]

Comment: Rather than switch suppliers, I suggest buying ten red flats and gluing them together.

Comment: Suppliers is a non-issue, but it's an interesting idea. However, it assumes that the flats (which I don't own) each have a mass of 100 g and that the necessary glue will be close to 0 g.  :-)

Comment: Ah, I assumed from your question that the cube was the only one that was out of scale.  (It seems plausible that the other three sizes would all be made from the same solid material, but I don't have my own set to check.)  If you use enough glue that its weight is a factor, you can cut or chisel away an appropriate amount from the middle of an interior flat to compensate.

Comment: Imagine a decimeter cube filled with water.  That is 1 kg (almost exactly).  It would be quite heavy.  You can't make them from wood, it is too light.  There are some types of plastic that are this heavy.  The question is:  does it float in water (too light) or sink (to heavy)?

Comment: Since there are 1 cm cubes, made of plastic, that weigh 1 g (also called “gram cubes”), I assume it’s reasonable that that same material could be used to make a 1 kg decimeter cube. No?

Comment: I would consider asking a woodworker friend to make one from a solid block of wood, probably cut into two pieces with a cavity bored into the center of each side. Add an appropriate weight to that cavity and restrain it, perhaps by using something like spray foam insulation. Then glue the two pieces together to make the cube. They could paint it or even score the lines in the faces if necessary.

Comment: Isn't water that density ? I seem to recall $1000 kg/m^3$ so, if we have $(0.1m)^3 = 0.001m^3$ then $m = \rho V = (1000 kg/m^3)(0.001m^3) = 1 kg$. You just need a cubic container to fill with water. The weight of the plastic container is small in comparison to the water.

Comment: Ice is close, it doesn't need a container if you want to cheat a bit.

Comment: Yes, liquid water is the ideal *density*, but it’s not my ideal *manipulative*. It can’t be carried around, dropped on the ground, or stored without risk of spillage. Plus it would look very different from its Base 10 cousins.

Comment: I don't know if this would work, but ABS is the plastic which Lego's and many other plastic toys are made from, and it has a density close to 1. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylonitrile_butadiene_styrene) You can't use Lego's, because they have lots of air in them. But I found a vendor offering solid blocks of ABS (https://www.plastiblocks.com/shop/ABS-Blocks-p100906003), so maybe you could cut some of that to size?